# call to undefined method llluminate\database\Eloquent\Collection::links()

Tags: laravel

I have been having pagination problems over 2days n still can't figure it out.

**Problem**

I have configured my `app/config/view.php`

```
'pagination' => 'pagination::simple;
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
Public function getEmails{

$emails= Email::all()->paginate(10);

return View::make('emails.index')->with('emails',$emails);

}
```

**VIEW**

```
..........
@foreach($emails as email)

{{$email->image}}

{{$email->description}}

{{$email->pricing}}

@endforeach

{{$emails->links()}}.........
```

**Problem:**

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are requesting conflicting information. Try changing this:

```
$emails= Email::all()->paginate(10);
```

To this:

```
$emails= Email::paginate(10);
```

Comment: Actually this {{$emails -links()}} is a typing error I made but in my code is actually {{$emails->links()}}

Comment: Bt still once I try to view it I still get the same error